# Read Data from kafka topic into spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

```
private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger LOGGER = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(sparkSqlMysql.class);

private static final SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("Spark2JdbcDs")
        .getOrCreate();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // JDBC connection properties


    // Load MySQL query result as Dataset

    Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.readStream().format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
            .option("subscribe", "SqlMessages").load();
```

I want to do something where I can read data from my spark SQL from my  kafka topic but not able to do so .

Can someone guide who I can convert my data from kafka Topic to spark SQL ?

Something where I can do this

```
 Dataset<Row> schoolData = sparkSession.sql("select * from Schools");
```

Answer (score 0):

Was doing something similar today. Consumed entire topic from beginning, converted to DataFrame and Saved as Parquet table. You can adapt my code from Scala, idea should be clear.

```scala
val topic = "topic_bla_bla"
val brokers = "some_kafka_broker:9092"
val kafkaDF = spark.read.format("kafka").option("kafkaConsumer.pollTimeoutMs", "20000").option("startingOffsets", "earliest").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers).option("subscribe", topic).load()
val jsonDF = kafkaDF.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
val finalDF = spark.read.option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json(jsonDF.as[String])
finalDF.registerTempTable("wow_table")
//OR
finalDF.write.format("parquet").saveAsTable("default.wow_table")
spark.sql("select * from wow_table")
```

Comment: Can you do it in Java?

Comment: @AdityaVerma You should be able. Idea is to read data via spark.read.format("kafka") from kafka, selecting and casting value as string, converting DataFrame to Dataset so you can do spark.read.option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json(...).